# ¿Cómo puedo mantener el mismo estilo del input hora tanto en Firefox como en Chrome?

Tags: html, css, angular-material, navegador-web, firefox

Cómo puedo mantener el mismo estilo del input hora tanto en Firefox como en Chrome. Lo quiero como en firefox. Estoy usando angular material

firefox input time:
[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

chrome input time:

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

```html
<mat-form-field appearance="outline">
                  <mat-label>Hora hasta</mat-label>
                  <input matInput type="time" name="d4" [(ngModel)]="updateModel.horaHasta[0]" [min]="minHour" max="23:59">
                </mat-form-field>
```

Answer (score 2):

Esto te puede ayudar,

https://www.w3schools.com/cssref/css3_browsersupport.php

Hay cieras propiedades que en otros navegadores se ven distintas, lo que puedes hacer es referenciarlo a cada navegador o bien, usar referencias css mas generales que cualquier navegador las identifique. De aquí, ya todo depende lo que vayas hacer.

```
/* Estilo para Chrome */
input[type="time"]::-webkit-datetime-edit {
  color: #333; /* Color del texto */
  background-color: #fff; /* Color de fondo */
}

/* Estilo para Firefox */
input[type="time"]::-moz-time-text {
  color: #333; /* Color del texto */
  background-color: #fff; /* Color de fondo */
}
```

O bien, estilos mas generales.

```
input[type="time"] {
  color: #333; /* Color del texto */
  background-color: #fff; /* Color de fondo */
}
```

Espero que esto te ayude!

Answer (score 0):

Al final lo he resuelto de esta manera, aplicando las modificaciones para cualquier navegador menos Firefox. La clase 'timeBox' se la he agregado a mi input de tipo 'time'.

```css
@supports not (-moz-appearance:none) {
    input[type="time"]::-webkit-calendar-picker-indicator {
        width: 18px;
        height:18px;
    }

    .timeBox {
        margin-top: 8px;
        height: 9px;
    }

    input[type=time] {
        line-height: 0.8;
    }
}
```